# Can Java initialize the objects in an array of objects similar to C++, without having to loop and call new?

Tags: java, c++, arrays, initialization

In C++, the code `Card cards[20];` initializes 20 Card objects, whereas in Java, the code `Card[] cards = new Card[20];` initializes an array that can hold 20 Card objects, but the Card objects aren't actually initialized. You have to do

```
for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    cards[i] = new Card();
}
```

Is there any way to avoid having to do this in Java, similar to C++?

Comment: In Java you cannot declare objects, only object references.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is not.

Array elements are values.

For reference types, that value is a reference. The default initialization value for references is `null`. That's the value that each element in the array will be initialized to. You have to explicitly initialize the elements yourself to reference new objects.

For primitive types, that value is the primitive type value, a `char`, an integer, a floating point value, or a boolean. The default value for those is `'\u0000'`, `0`, `0.0`, and `false`, respectively. That's the value that each element in the array will be initialized to.

Comment: What about arrays of primitives?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Elements of arrays of primitives are also initialized to their default value, 0 or `false`. Are you asking me to add that to the answer? I'll do that now.

Comment: Not a big deal, but I think your sentence *"An array in java holds references."* may mislead someone into thinking that arrays of primitives are not possible or are implemented with auto-boxing.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yeah, I had that impression too. Made it cleaner and clearer.

Comment: and `'\u0000'` for `char`

Comment: @Pshemo If that helps understand it from a `char` point of view, but `'\u0000'` is equal to `0`.

Comment: Yes `'\u0000'` is equal to `0` but some people don't like to mix them claiming that `char c = 0` is too often (wrongly) understood as `char c = '0'`. Sometimes it is good to be explicit and write `char c = '\u0000'` or `char c = '\0'` (even in notes or answers).

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no purely-array-way of doing what you want. If you don't want to use loops explicitly for this problem, then one of alternative ways could be using streams (added in Java 8).

```
Card[] cards  = Stream.generate(Card::new).limit(20).toArray(Card[]::new);
```

or maybe using [`Arrays.setAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll-T:A-java.util.function.IntFunction-) will be less cryptic

```
Card[] cards  = new Card[20];
Arrays.setAll(cards, i -> new Card());
```

Comment: @HotLicks Believe it or not, there are some people to whom this actually *is* simpler and clearer :)

Comment: @HotLicks For me, yes, but it depends on personal preferences :) Anyway it is just an alternative.

Comment: No offense, but this looks like taken straight from a code obfuscation contest. Is this coding style really considered superior by renowned Java experts?

Comment: @ChristianHackl You get used to the notation very quickly, though I can't say I've used it (or that I'm a renowned Java expert).

Comment: Looks very complicated and is doing too much for the mentioned purpose.

Comment: I think the `setAll` version reads much clearer, and may actually be a better choice than the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ equivalent of a Java `Card[] cards = new Card[20];` would roughly be `Card* cards[20];` (or `std::array<Card*, 20> cards;` in modern C++).

And as it turns out, you have to explicitly initialize every array element in C++ as well, if you want those pointers to actually point to `Card` objects in memory:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
    cards[i] = new Card;
}
```

There is no Java equivalent for the C++ `Card card[20]`, for the same reason that there is no Java equivalent for a C++ `Card single_card;`.